# how to add event listener in tinymce of text mode

Tags: jquery

I want to detect the users input in wordpress by tinymce. But the text mode is not working.

Only if I first use visual mode and then switch the text mode, the text can be detected.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('keyup_event', function(editor, url) {
  // Create keyup event
  editor.on('keyup', function(e) {

    // Get the editor content (html)
    get_ed_content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
    // Do stuff here... (run do_stuff_here() function)
    console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor);
    do_stuff_here(get_ed_content);
    if (get_ed_content.indexOf("&lt;iframe&gt;") > 0 && flag1 === true) {
      createMessage();
    } else if (get_ed_content.indexOf("&lt;iframe&gt;") < 0) {
      flag1 = true;
      $('#detect').remove();
    }
  });
});

$('#content').on('keyup', function(e) {
  get_ed_content = $('#content').val();
  // get_ed_content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
  do_stuff_here(get_ed_content);
  console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor);
  if (get_ed_content.indexOf("<iframe>") > 0 && flag2 === true) {
    createMessage();
  } else if (get_ed_content.indexOf("<iframe>") < 0){
    flag2 = true;
    $('#detect').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: I have already putted the code in ready's function of jquery

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, you are trying to get the selected/marked content. For example, if i mark a permalink then i gill get bla. If so, what you need to do is this-

```
    ed.addButton ('remark', { // Remark Text
        title : 'Remark Text',
        image: url + '../../images/remark-icon.png',
        onClick : function() {
            var state = true;
            ed.focus();

            ed.controlManager.setActive('remark', state);

            var text = ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'});

            var selected_elem = ed.selection.getNode(); // Get selected element
            selected_elem = jQuery(selected_elem); // Get element's class
            var elem_type = ed.selection.getNode().nodeName; // Get element type

            if( elem_type !== 'SPAN' ) {
                ed.selection.setContent('<span class="remark-text">' + text + '</span>');
            }
            else {
                var selected_content = ed.selection.getNode();
                var stripped_content = selected_content.innerHTML;

                ed.selection.getNode().remove();
                ed.selection.setContent( stripped_content );
            }

            ed.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
                elem_type = ed.selection.getNode().nodeName;

                if( elem_type == 'SPAN' && selected_elem.find("span").hasClass("remark-text") ) {
                    state = true;
                    ed.controlManager.setActive('remark', state);
                }
                else {
                    state = false;
                    ed.controlManager.setActive('remark', state);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So i have an addButton which creates my button. Then, onClick function i need to get the selected node using-

```
ed.focus();
ed.controlManager.setActive('remark', state);
var text = ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'});
var selected_elem = ed.selection.getNode();
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for you help.I only want to detect the user's input.And when i first choose text mode,the detecting is not working..but when i first choose visual mode and then switch the text mode the detecting is working